# PostgreSQL: subquery must return one column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Looking obvious error, still see no chance to find it. I've made to localize error in this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION findRecipientsByQuestion(questionId BIGINT)
RETURNS SETOF BIGINT AS $$
DECLARE
  question questionObject;  

  BEGIN
    question := (
      SELECT "a"."id", "a"."body", "a"."author_id", "a"."category_id", "a"."urgent", "a"."created_at", "a"."locale_id", "a"."lat", "a"."lng", "a"."radius" 
      FROM "question" "a" 
      WHERE "a"."id"=questionId 
      LIMIT 1
    );


    RETURN QUERY SELECT "a"."id" 
    FROM "user" "a" INNER JOIN "notifications" "b" ON ("a"."id"="b"."user_id")
    WHERE ("b"."category_id"=question.category_id OR "b"."urgent") AND 
        isGeoMatch("a"."lat", "a"."lng", "a"."radius", question.lat, question.lng, question.radius);
  END 
  $$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Which uses this type:

```
CREATE TYPE questionObject AS (
  id BIGINT,
  body VARCHAR,
  author_id BIGINT,
  category_id BIGINT,
  urgent BOOLEAN,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  locale_id BIGINT,
  lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
  lng DOUBLE PRECISION,
  radius INTEGER
);
```

And I'm getting this error in runtime:

```
Error: subquery must return only one column
```

Comment: You have, in fact, two queries. Did you try each separately? Which one is triggering the error?

Comment: good notice let me try

Comment: well, problem is in the first query....

Comment: I don't know the details of posgresql... Does it support `SELECT .... INTO...`? If yes, you may wish to re-phrase the query.

Comment: You either `select into` as in @Juan answer or do `question := (select ("a"."id", ...) from ...)`

Comment: btw no need to use so many `""` unless you have uppercase and spaces in the variables name. So suggestion dont use uppercase or spaces to keep code simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with my type

```
CREATE TYPE map.get_near_link AS
   (link_id integer,
    distance integer,
    direction integer,
    geom public.geometry(4));
```

I do

```
sRow map.get_near_link;

SELECT i.Link_ID, i.Distance, i.Direction, i.geom into sRow 
FROM 
    index_query i;
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job ;) And another thanks for the "" advice.

Answer (score 3):

I would just get rid off all the complexity and make it plain sql:

```
create or replace function findrecipientsbyquestion (
    _questionid bigint
) returns setof bigint as $$

    select a.id 
    from
        user a
        inner join
        notifications b on a.id = b.user_id
        inner join (
            select categoty_id, lat, lng, radius 
            from question
            where id = _questionid 
            limit 1
        ) q on q.category_id = b.category_id or b.urgent
    where isgeomatch(a.lat, a.lng, a.radius, q.lat, q.lng, q.radius);

$$ language sql;
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, this definitely looks cleaner than my sollution